# How can I insert the query result into a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I wrote the following sql code in mysql:

```
SELECT replace(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(server_name,':'),server_id),':'),1),'='), flag), ',', '') result
FROM (SELECT f.name server_name,f.id server_id, group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(sgk.NAME,';') ,sgk.id),';'),1),';'),sgk.nagios_id ),'|') as flag
 FROM complex_check cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check sgk,functionalci f ,lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg
WHERE cc.id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.id = lk.single_check_id AND sgk.id = lkcg.single_check_id AND lkcg.config_item_id = f.id GROUP BY f.NAME) x
```

with this sql code, I can get the following result:

```
result 
INFRASEP01:32:1=cpu check01;1;1;2|DB check sep01;3;1;2|disk space check sep01;2;1;3|
INFRASEP02:33:1=cpu check sep02;4;1;2|db check sep02;5;1;23|disk space check sep02;6;1;2|
INFRAVICO04:35:1=cpu check04;7;1;2|db check CO04;8;1;2|disk space check CO04;9;1;2|
```

I want to inser the result into the "pfm_result_data" table (which has two attributes:id is int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL and primary key of the table;result_list is text NULL ).I wrote the following code to insert data into the "pfm_result_data" table:

```
INSERT INTO pfm_result_data (result_list) VALUES (here is sql sentence which I wrote above)
```

But, I couldn't insert data into the "pfm_result_data"  table. could you help to correct my insert sentence , please ? ...

thanks a lot !

Best regards,

Anwar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into pfm_result_data(result_list) 
    <your query here>;
```

You do not need the `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, it works correct , I got the expected result ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

INSERT.. SELECT Statement:

```
INSERT INTO pfm_result_data 
    (
     your_field
    ) 
    SELECT replace(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(server_name,':'),server_id),':'),1),'='), flag), ',', '') AS result
    FROM (SELECT f.name server_name,f.id server_id, group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(sgk.NAME,';') ,sgk.id),';'),1),';'),sgk.nagios_id ),'|') as flag
     FROM complex_check cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check sgk,functionalci f ,lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg
    WHERE cc.id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.id = lk.single_check_id AND sgk.id = lkcg.single_check_id AND lkcg.config_item_id = f.id GROUP BY f.NAME) x
```

Comment: Hi Galma, Now it works correct , I got the expected result ! Thanks a lot !